# How to calculate CPU utilization of windows web server in Grafana

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana

I'm using prometheus as a data source and in grafana i want to make CPU utlization graph with accurate values and less interval

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter

Answer (score -1):

since you are using Prometheus you can use "node_exporter" , https://www.robustperception.io/understanding-machine-cpu-usage

Comment: i'm using blackbox exporter its windows server